# ImportError: No module named multipart

Tags: linux, python-2.7

When I run the script.py file, it is executed successfully, but when I try to run the script.exe file created using the pyinstaller, I get the below given error.

Not exactly the exe file its created in the dist folder as only script.

**ImportError: No module named multipart**

So what has to be done to solve the above error kindly guide.

Imports used:

```
import email
import email.encoders
import email.mime.text
import smtplib
```

exact_ error:

```
Traceback:
File "script.py",line 192, in<module>
File "script.py/__init__.py", line 493, in run_prnding
File "script.py/__init__.py", line 78, in run_pending
File "script.py/__init__.py", line 131, in_run_job
File "script.py/__init__.py", line 411, in run
File "script.py", line 110, in job
File "email/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
ImportError: No module named multipart
```

Note : This error is seen only in raspbian_stretch_lite and Dietpi

Comment: Please create a minimal example that shows the problem. Or at the very least, show the imports of your `script.py`.

Comment: I have added as you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is given due to missing hidden-import used by the pyinstaller, py2exe,bb_freeze.

Solution: create exe file by adding the hook/adding hidden import command

sudo pyinstaller --onefile script.py --hidden-import=email.mime.multipart